# What's the most concise way to create a Task that never returns?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await, task

For testing purposes, I need to mock a `Task`-returning method on an interface handing back a task that never runs the continuation. Here's the code I have so far:

```
// FooTests.cs

[Test]
public void Foo()
{
    var yielder = Substitute.For<IYielder>();
    yielder.YieldAsync().Returns(ThreadingUtilities.NeverReturningTask);

    ...
}

// ThreadingUtilities.cs

using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Repository.Editor.Android.UnitTests.TestInternal.Threading
{
    internal static class ThreadingUtilities
    {
        public static Task NeverReturningTask { get; } = CreateNeverReturningTask();

        private async static Task CreateNeverReturningTask()
        {
            await new StopAwaitable();
            Debug.Fail("Execution shouldn't reach here.");
        }
    }
}

// StopAwaitable.cs

using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

namespace Repository.Editor.Android.UnitTests.TestInternal.Threading
{
    internal struct StopAwaitable : INotifyCompletion
    {
        public bool IsCompleted => false;

        public StopAwaitable GetAwaiter() => this;

        public void GetResult()
        {
            Debug.Fail("The continuation shouldn't have been posted!");
        }

        public void OnCompleted(Action continuation)
        {
            // Ignore the continuation.
        }
    }
}
```

Here, I've created a custom awaitable type that simply ignores the continuation handed to it-- `await new StopAwaitable()` has essentially the same effect as a `return` from a sync method. Then, I await it in an `async Task` method, creating a `Task` object that will never run the continuation.

My question is, is this the most concise/clear way to do this? Is there any other way to create such a task that doesn't involve a custom awaitable, which will confuse people unfamiliar w/ how `async` works?

Comment: There are often cases in test code where you want quick'n'dirty solutions, I'm glad someone already asked and asnwered this one

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use:

```
var taskThatNeverReturns = Task.Delay(Timeout.Infinite);
```

The [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194873(v=vs.110).aspx) states that the parameter represents:

> The number of milliseconds to wait before completing the returned task, or -1 to wait indefinitely.

[`Timeout.Infinite`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.timeout.infinite) is a constant field with a value of `-1`.

Comment: @JamesKo if, for cleanup purposes you need to end this infinite `Task`, pass in a `CancellationToken` to the `Task.Delay` overload!

Answer (score 14):

I hope I'm reading the question correctly here...

```
return new System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSource<object>().Task;
```

1. Return the task created by a Task Completion Source.
2. Never set the source to complete.

Continuations will never be invoked and `await` will 'block' forever.